# Jenkins is throwing the error "Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?"

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

- Environment - Using Java with Eclipse Framework - TestNg Build
  Automation Tool - Apache Maven

I have installed Jenkins on a remote machine. The POM is located on my local machine where I have my eclipse installed.

I am getting the error when I try to run Jenkins
 "Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?"

Please find my configuration below

[image]

Here is my error message

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would expect that to work.

It's traditional to check out the project/pom from source control (Git, SVN, etc). Then the file exists in the Jenkins workspace and Jenkins can find it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want to check before I upload to Git

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277645/no-such-file-issue-when-running-jenkins-on-linux-server-but-its-working-when-jen

Comment: I have tried with Bitbucket repo url too but its not working